# why the content of the activity doesn't appear (in android)?

Tags: android

I start a new activity when clicking on a button , but the content(ui components) of the new activity doesn't appear , why ??

```
button listener to start new activity 
  m_sendButton.setOnClickListener(
      new OnClickListener(){
       public void onClick(View view) {
       Intent in = new Intent(context, SendMessageForm.class);                      
      // i.putExtra("id","4");
       context.startActivity(in); 
       //Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Error. Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       //toast.show();

        } }

    );
```

SendMessageForm.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SendMessageForm extends Activity {

 public void onCreat(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.search_result_form);
 }

}
```

search_result_form.xml (just for test)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:id="@+id/rootLayout"

    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button android:text="Send" android:id="@+id/btnBacksds" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your onCreate method. The method name says onCreat - it's missing an 'e':

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SendMessageForm extends Activity {

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.search_result_form);
   }

}
```

In general it's useful to use the `@Override` annotation to help you catch any mistakes such as this.  If the parent class does not have a matching method signature then your IDE (at least Eclipse does this) will warn you or present an error.

Comment: @roundhill, good catch, I updated my response with the correction. Thanks. An answer isn't useful if it presents another error :P

Comment: You're welcome adham. If this answer is correct, go ahead and mark the answer as accepted so others know that the question was properly answered.